# Sending arrays with alphanumeric indexes names through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass an array through jquery ajax call. However, I need to use descriptive indexes on it eg. item["sku"] = 'abc';

If I create a following array:

```
item[1] = "abc";
item[2] = "def";
```

and pass it to below ajax call, I get a proper array on the php end

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/add_to_cart.php",
    data: {items: item},
    success: function(msg){ }
});
```

However, creating array like that

```
item["sku"] = "abc";
item["title"] = "product";
```

produces nothing on the php end

Is there a trick to push such array through? I've tried with jquery stringify but this didn't help

Also, I will need to pass 2-dimensional array in similar matter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're creating an Array instance with either the [] literal or new Array().  The data structure you're looking for though is called an Object in JavaScript, they can also be referred to as associative arrays, hashmaps, or dictionaries in other environments.  To create and fill an object in JavaScript you can do something like this:

```
var item = {};
item["sku"] = "abc";
item["title"] = "product";
```

Comment: json_decode would probably work and will definitely use it when there's no other way, but this simple trick to create object instead of  array, sorted everything. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may construct and send collected product data like this:

```
var item = [{sku:"abc", title:"product1"}, {sku:"def", title:"product2"}, {sku:"ghi", title:"product3"}];

$.ajax({          
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/add_to_cart.php",
    data: {items: JSON.stringify(item)},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){ }
});
```

json_decode() will help you out on the PHP end:

```
<?php
    var_dump(json_decode($_REQUEST['items'], true));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take a hard look at PHP's `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php (truly the whole library will be helpful) as well as jQuery's `$.getJSON()` and `$.post()` functions: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
<?php

$items_array = json_decode( $_REQUEST['items'], true );

foreach ( $items_array as $key=>$value ){
    // $key = 'sku', 'title', etc.
    // $value = 'abc', 'product', etc.
    // $value might include array( 'key'=>'value', 'key'=>'value' ) when multidimensional
}
```

Comment: hi, I know json_encode(). Are you saying that php is able to create an array from POST when array indexes are numbers, but it requires json_encode when array indexes are alphanumerical?

Comment: hi, sorry I updated my answer, should use json_decode() which will allow processing of alphanumeric arrays and multi-dimensional arrays. json_encode() and $.getJSON() will help you work with data returned by PHP (I assume you'll have data coming both ways eventually)